# I'd like to make this relational database into a star schema. Any help is appreciated

Tags: ssms

[image: ERD of relational database]

So basically, I want to make this relational database into a star schema. This would revolve around a sales fact table. Although I am confused as how to do so because there are two ways in which a sale is made. Either through a store sale or internet sale. That part is kind of messing with how I would build my facts and dimensions table. Do I just make the sales fact table include the store id and leave it as null if it were a internet sale, or do I make those two items a dimension such as internet sale dim and store sale dim?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new row to your store dimension table for „website“. And add a column StoreType that says „Physical“ and „Web“ for instance. Then all sales go into the same fact table, no matter whether they occur in a physical store or online.